# Intro class Issue with finding a circle radius in C++

Tags: c++

I need help to find the radius of a circle. I got an error because I was trying to take the answer from distance can't take the answer from the double distance formula and plug it into the radius equation I made. I am not sure how to go about doing this. Is there a way to take the answer I get from the circumference and plug it into the radiance equation in order to use r=c/2pi find out what the radiance would be? I tried to do that but I am getting an error. I probably am doing it incorrect, or it just isn't supposed to work.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double distance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);
double radius(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);
double circumference(double radius);
double area(double radius);

int main()
{
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    double rad, dis, cir, a;

    cout << "Enter the x-coordinate for the center of the circle: ";
    cin >> x1;
    cout << "Enter the y-coordinate for the center of the circle: ";
    cin >> y1;
    cout << "Enter the x-coordinate for the point on the circle: ";
    cin >> x2;
    cout << "Enter the y-coordinate for the point on the circle: ";
    cin >> y2;

    dis = distance(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    rad = radius(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    cir = circumference(rad);
    a = area(rad);

    cout << "\n\nThe distance between the two points is: " << dis << endl;
    cout << "The radius of the circle is: " << rad << endl;
    cout << "The circumference of the circle is: " << cir << endl;
    cout << "The area of the circle is: " << a << endl;

    return 0;
}

double distance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    double dist = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);

    return dist;
}

double radius(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    return radius(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    return radius;
}
radius = circumference / 2 * pi

double circumference(double rad)
{
    double pi = 3.1416;
    return (pi * rad * 2);
}

double area(double rad)
{
    double pi = 3.1416;
    return (pi * rad * rad);
}
```

Comment: I think they meant to write
    double radius(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
    {
        return distance(x1,x2,y1,y2);
    }

Answer (score 2):

What error do you get?

```
    double radius(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
    {
        return radius(x1,x2,y1,y2);
return radius;
    }
radius=circumference/2*pi
```

^ this seems to be your problem, it certainly won't compile

Of course, if you define circumference in terms of a call the the radius() function, and also want to define radius in terms of a call to the circumference() function it's not going to work.
You need to define at least one of these independently.

Comment: This is maths question, not a c++ question - but (if I understand correctly what you are trying to do), the distance between the centre of the circle and a point on the circle _is_ the radius, so you can define radius in terms of distance

Answer (score 0):

As @benroberts999 mentioned, an error lies in your radius function.

You want to define the radius function to calculate the distance between (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) inside the brackets of the function definition.  Since you've already imported `cmath`, try replacing your radius function with this.

```
double radius(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    double radius = sqrt(pow((x2-x1), 2) + pow((y2-y1), 2);   //sqrt of dist x^2+y^2
    return radius;
}
```

Hope that helps.